# ios Facebook Invite to Event (id)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Im wondering how to invite friends , specified with id's in nsarray. I want to invite all friends to event(with id), i read few q&a here but there wasn't about event invitation. I couldn't find any example with Event Invite. Can anyone provide me a example?

Comment: Have you tried setting tags on open graph action like this: `[action setTags:@[@"{friend-user-id-1}", @"{friend-user-id-2}"]];`

Comment: How to specify the eventid ? i know how to join to event, but how to invite?